# Arraylist, date and threads

Tags: java, multithreading, date, arraylist

This is a bank account simulation program, I was looking to add the date to the transaction using frequency of the transaction to add the date to the calendar, thus increasing the date correctly for each transaction. However when I call to get the date within another class, it gives me the total added date for each transaction. So say four weeks pass, it would show each transaction happening on those four weeks, instead of each week.
The system.out.println at the bottom prints out the correct date to the console, so I assume its something to do with the way I'm storing it in the arraylist.

I'd be glad if someone could show me where I'm going wrong.

```
 public void run() {
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    while (duration > 0) {
        duration--;
        if (duration % freq == 0) {
            if (type == false) {
                this.withdraw(amount, billName);
                Transaction out = new Transaction(billName, amount, "Out",date);
                transList.add(out);
                date.setTime( calendar.getTime().getTime());
                calendar.setTime(date);
                calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, freq*7);
                date.setTime( calendar.getTime().getTime());
            } else {
               this.deposit(amount, billName);
               Transaction in = new Transaction(billName, amount, "In",date);
               transList.add(in);
            }
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println(date);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(
               DepositThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }            
}

public void sortType( String sortPara ) {
   trans.setText("");
   for(int i=0; i<transList.size();i++){
      String textArea = trans.getText();
      transList.get(i).getDate();
      if(transList.get(i).type.equals(sortPara)) {
         System.out.println(transList.get(i).getName());
         trans.setText(textArea+transList.get(i).getName()+
            "       "+String.valueOf(transList.get(i).getAmount())+"     "+ 
            transList.get(i).getDate()+"\n");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please try to be more clear, stil trying to figure out what you said

Comment: Sorry, basically it should add the date to a transaction, then increase the date by 1 week, then add it to another transaction. This should give different dates for each transaction, however its just showing the final date on both transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the same muteable date object to all your Transactions and then you start changing it with: 
`date.setTime( calendar.getTime().getTime());`.

Make your date object immutable and create a new one for every transaction.

Comment: i was writing an answer when you posted about the same :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same Date.

Change

```
 Transaction out = new Transaction(billName, amount, "Out",date);
```

to

```
 Transaction out = new Transaction(billName, amount, "Out", new Date(date));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! yes that it made it work :) Simple mistake now I know the answer.